# Exporting All Grid Data to PDF

Tags: pdf, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-mvc

I know that I can force the Kendo grid to export all of the data in it if I opt to export to Excel.

I simply can't seem to find an equivalent for PDF.

Is there one?

Answer (score 0):

I've just seen the release notes for Q1 2015 (released today) and PDF export no includes an AllPages option like the Excel export.

Answer (score 0):

Just add these options to your grid definition properties

```
    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        toolbar: ["pdf"],
        pdf: {
            allPages: true,
            fileName: "Kendo UI Grid Export.pdf", //optional
            proxyURL: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/export" //optional
        },
        ....
```

I should do the trick